# outline numbering for Word 2003

Tags: microsoft-word, outline

I've created an outline in MS Word 2003 by using View -> Outline and using the promote/demote toolbar buttons to move various paragraphs to different levels.

It views and prints fine, with additional indenting for each level of the outline.

Now I want to add outline numbering and I can't get it to work. I've tried Format -> Bullets and Numbering, and it treats all the items in the outline as at the same level for numbering purposes.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears not to work if you try to use the same paragraph style for all levels. I had to use a separate paragraph style for each level, and then it worked OK.